# @Composable invocations con only happen from thhe context of an @Composable function

Tags: android, kotlin

lo que estoy tratando de hacer es traer datos de firebase y luego mostrarlos en pantalla como un texto utilizando Jetpack Composer

```
@Composable
fun showList(user:String){
 db.collection(myCollection).document(user).get().addOnSuccessListener {
    if(it.exist()){
      val datos = it.get("list_data")
      val listDatos = listOf(datos)
      for(data in listDatos){
          Text(text=data) //funcion composable
      }
    }
  }
```

sin enbargo me da el error @Composable invocations con only happen from thhe context of an @Composable function y no se a que se debe

Comment: No veo uses el contexto, quita la anotacion @Composable.

Comment: si la quito el Text() ya no funcionaria ya que es de compose, no?

Comment: Agrega Text() por favor

Comment: si esta, es el que tiene el comentario de funcion composable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las *composable functions* son como las *suspend functions* de kotlin, en el sentido de que sólo se pueden llamar desde un contexto específico. Al escribir dentro de `addOnSuccessListener` pierdes ese contexto y por lo tanto no podrás llamar ningún composable.

Esta es una forma de resolverlo:

1. Agregar la siguiente dependencia (opcional pero recomendado)

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.4.3"
```

Esto te permite usar `await` para reemplazar los callbacks de las consultas a firebase y a cualquier otra api de google.

2. Crear una clase para gestionar el estado de las consultas

```
sealed class FirebaseResult<T> {
    class Success<T>(val data: T) : FirebaseResult<T>()
    class Failed<T>(val exception: Exception) : FirebaseResult<T>()
}
```

3. Crear una función que traiga los datos (opcional pero recomendado)

```
suspend fun getUserData(user: String): FirebaseResult<List<String>> = try {
    val snapshot = db.collection(myCollection).document(user).get().await()
    val data = snapshot.get("list_data") as List<String>
    FirebaseResult.Success(data)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    FirebaseResult.Failed(e)
}
```

4. Agregarle estado a tu composable

```
@Composable
fun showList(user: String) {
    val (result, updateResult) = remember {
        mutableStateOf<FirebaseResult<List<String>>?>(null)
    }
    when (result) {
        // valor inicial, significa que la consulta no se ha realizado
        null -> {
            CircularProgressIndicator() // opcional
            rememberCoroutineScope().launch {
                // updateResult hace que la función se ejecute denuevo
                // guardando el resultado de la consulta
                updateResult(getUserData(user))
            }
        }
        is FirebaseResult.Failed -> {
            // has algo con esto
            val e = result.exception
        }
        is FirebaseResult.Success -> {
            // He aquí el poder de jetpack compose. Esta única línea está
            // remplazado un recycler view, su adapter y su viewHolder
            LazyColumn { items(result.data) { Text(it) } }
        }
    }
}
```

Lee más sobre cómo gestionar estados [aquí](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state)

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sacaste de un gran problema para mi

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido. Como fan de kotlin me encanta ayudar a personas que usan este lenguaje. Por cierto deberías agregar a tus preguntas el tag `android`, kotlin en un lenguaje multiplatform. Y saca `composer` eso es algo de php, no hay tag para jetpack compose

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación, una cosa... como utilizo la funcion suspend?

Comment: no entiendo la pregunta, ya te mostré como usarla. Si quieres saber cómo aplicarla a un caso específico, sería mejor que hagas otro post. Si quieres información general puedes leer la [documentación oficial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-guide.html)

Comment: listo, gracias.